# incorporate a html-css template as master page in asp.net- mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website, and want to do it using MVC 4. I dont want to use the custom asp.net template, and the asp.net templates available online do not meet my requirements. I have designed a html-css template and need to incorporate it into my project...(pretty much build the "contents folder" of the default templated mvc 4 project myself, if u know what i mean)...

I would really appreciate if someone points me to a tutorial or gives me a step-by-step account of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much looking for how to use [Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx).   You can have as many as you'd like.

Comment: tell me if i am wrong...but this article is building the layout of the template...i "have" a html-css template built already...is there no way i could incorporate that into the project?

Comment: @aromore I think you need to clarify your question. The core concept is that you can use whatever HTML/CSS you can think of for your `_Layout.cshtml` (aka "template") and mix in the proper sections (if you need them).

Comment: alright, i think i get it...i ll work on what u guys have suggested here...and post more queries...thx all!!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you simply want to apply your template to `_Layout.cshtml`. This is similar in purpose to a MasterPage in ASP.NET web forms.

Here's a [ScottGu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) on layouts and sections. (Just noticed that's the same link provided by @ErikPhilips)

To provide a simple explanation. `_Layout.cshtml` resides at `Project\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`. By default it looks like a normal HTML file with a couple of unusual lines. The most important being `@RenderBody()`. When returning a `ViewResult` from an action (e.g. `return View("MyView, myModel)`), your view gets rendered by `@RenderBody` inside the layout. You can do what you like with `_Layout.cshtml` and if you're brave, you can also nest layouts.